# React - onChange function 'this.state' is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experimenting with React and I'm trying to create a Search to filter a list of items. I have two components, the main one displaying the list of items which calls the Search component.

I have an `onChange` function that sets the `term` in the state as the input value and then calls `searchItems` from the main component to filter the list of items. For some reason in `searchItems`, `this.state` is undefined. I thought adding `bind` to `onInputChange` in the Search component would sort it out but it did not make any difference. Maybe there's something I'm missing.

**Main Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import Search from './search';

class Items extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("[url].json")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result
                    });
                }
            ),
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                })
            }
    }

    searchItems(term) {
        const { items } = this.state;
        const filtered = _.filter(items, function(item) {
            return item.Name.indexOf(term) > -1;
        });

        this.setState({ items: filtered });
    }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        }
        else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Search onSearch={this.searchItems}/>
                    <ul>
                        {items.map(item => (
                            <li key={item.GameId}>
                                {item.Name}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default Items;
```

**Search Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            term: ''
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    onInputChange(term) {
        this.setState({ term });
        this.props.onSearch(term);
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You didn't bind `searchItems()` in the `Items` component.

Try changing it to an arrow function:

```
searchItems = () => {
  // blah
}
```

or otherwise binding it in the `constructor()`:

```
constructor() {
  // blah
  this.searchItems = this.searchItems.bind(this);
}
```

or when you call it.

You can read more about `this` [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).

Comment: Ah yes that did the trick! I'm quite new to React to be honest, am I right in saying that any functions that are used for certain events (such as onChange) or for updates need to be bound to access `this`?

Comment: In general, yes. You can read more on that [here](https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a).